# The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource.LoggingEventSource' threw an exception

Tags: c#, .net-8.0

I a running the dotnet 8 preview 7 and I keep getting the below error message when I make a call to `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()`.

**Stack Trace**

```
Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContextAttribute' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(QCallModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandle(Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(MetadataToken caCtorToken, MetadataImport& scope, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1& derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctorWithParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.IsCustomAttributeDefined(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Int32 attributeCtorToken, Boolean mustBeInheritable)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.IsDefined(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.ToString(TraceFormat traceFormat, StringBuilder sb)
   at System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.ToString(TraceFormat traceFormat)
   at System.Exception.get_StackTrace()
```

Any idea what I am missing. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

This project structure is CQRS so there is a couple of csproj files that I have listed the contents below

**Entry Application csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>
    
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="7.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore.Enrichers.CorrelationId" Version="1.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Exceptions" Version="8.4.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Async" Version="1.5.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\Jetpack.Extensions.Hosting\src\Jetpack.Extensions.Hosting\Jetpack.Extensions.Hosting.csproj" />
        <ProjectReference Include="..\CQRS.Application\CQRS.Application.csproj" />
        <ProjectReference Include="..\CQRS.Infrastructure\CQRS.Infrastructure.csproj" />
        <ProjectReference Include="..\CQRS.Persistence\CQRS.Persistence.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="appsettings.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Application csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="12.0.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NodaTime" Version="8.0.0-preview.4" />
      <PackageReference Include="Twilio" Version="6.11.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="WolverineFx" Version="1.5.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="WolverineFx.FluentValidation" Version="1.5.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\CQRS.Domain\CQRS.Domain.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Domain csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Folder Include="Enums\" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores" Version="8.0.0-preview.7.23375.9" />
      <PackageReference Include="NodaTime" Version="3.1.9" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Infrastructure csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\CQRS.Application\CQRS.Application.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>


    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Flurl.Http" Version="4.0.0-pre3" />
      <PackageReference Include="MailKit" Version="4.1.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="SendGrid" Version="9.28.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="Stripe.net" Version="41.27.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Twilio" Version="6.11.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Persistence csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <WarningsAsErrors>Nullable</WarningsAsErrors>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\CQRS.Application\CQRS.Application.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.0-preview.7.23375.9" />
      <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NodaTime" Version="8.0.0-preview.4" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
</Project>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre]? Please show the csproj file.

Comment: @GuruStron please see the update above.

Comment: Why do you have `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` package which is deprecated?

Comment: @GuruStron I was customizing Identity. What is the replacement.

Comment: Is not `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` enough?

Comment: Also based on the naming it should be part of the ASP.NET Core so you do not need to add is explicitly for correct project types. Just remove the package.

Comment: @GuruStron I thought it would be but for some reason SignInManager is not in  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore`. I was able to use. `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI`. However I still get the same error.

Comment: Please share the full code. [`SignInManager<TUser>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1?view=aspnetcore-8.0) should be in place.

Comment: @GuruStron please see this repo https://github.com/dblock247/CQRS-V8

Comment: @GuruStron so it seems that the issue comes when referencing a packages in Microsofts `8.0.0-preview.7.23375.6` versions. Downgrading to `8.0.0-preview.6.23329.7` versions seems to fix the issue.

Comment: Do you have [.NET 8 preview 7](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/8.0/preview/8.0.0-preview.7.md?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website) installed on your machine?

Comment: @GuruStron you are so right. I accidentally had the wrong version install. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use latest .NET latest preview packages be sure to install corresponding .NET preview version, in this case - [.NET 8.0.0 Preview 7](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/8.0/preview/8.0.0-preview.7.md?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website) .

P.S.

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` package is deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: Is there a alternative package or are they abandoning Identity?